# Borrar nodo arbol binario JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de eliminar un nodo de un arbol binario recursivamente en java mediante una funcion por referencia , pero no termino de entender sobre como borrar las referencias a los nodos, cuando sale de la recursividad no borra nada, ya intente con public Arbol y solo borra la raiz.
Si alguien puede darme un ejemplo sobre como se borran las referencias recursivamente, me salvaria:(

```
public class Arbol {
    private int dato;
    private Arbol izq, der;
    int cantidad;
    Arbol aux = null;
    int num2 = 0;

        public void buscando_reemplazo(Arbol nodo, Arbol anterior, int num) { //Busco un nodo que este mas a la derecha del izquierdo del nodo a eliminar y lo guardo en aux
            Arbol aux2 = anterior;
            if (num == 0) {
                buscando_reemplazo(nodo.izq, nodo, 1);
                num = 0;
            }
            if (num == 1) {
                if (nodo.der != null)
                    buscando_reemplazo(nodo.der, nodo, 1);
                if (num2 == 1) {
                    return;
                }
                aux = new Arbol(nodo.dato);
                aux2.der = null;
                num2 = 1;
    
            }
    
        }
    
        public int eliminar(Arbol arbol, int xdato) {//Funcion para eliminar un nodo 
                                                     // Ya intente con public Arbol, si elimina la raiz pero no a un nodo
    
            if (this.dato == xdato) {
                if (es_hoja(arbol) == 1) {
                    Arbol root = null;
                    arbol = root;
                    return 1;
    
                }
                if (es_nodo(arbol) == 1) {
                    buscando_reemplazo(arbol, null, 0);
                    aux.der = arbol.der;
                    aux.izq = arbol.izq;
                    arbol = aux;
    
                    
                    return 1;
                }
            }
    
            if (xdato > arbol.dato) {
                eliminar(arbol.der, xdato);
                return 1;
            } else {
                if (xdato < arbol.dato)
                    eliminar(arbol.izq, xdato);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: hola amigo, ya investigaste como de manejan variables por referencia???

Comment: Si leí un poco, pero siempre con algo básico y no orientado a objetos, tienes algún link?

Comment: tienes estos: [link 1](https://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/delete-node-binary-search-tree-bst/), [link 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-delete-a-tree/), [link 3](https://www.techiedelight.com/deletion-from-bst/), [link 4](https://medium.com/swlh/java-how-to-delete-a-node-in-binary-search-tree-aa2d4befe728),

Comment: referencia; https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/17161735 y https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reference-variable-in-java/

Comment: Gracias por los links amigo

Comment: de nada para eso estamos... si encuentras la solución te recomiendo agregarla para que luego la marques como resuelta. eso da puntos de reputación ...